overlay chromosome number to barplot in R
I want to add numbers above the chromosomes barplot.
The chromosome data is provided as integer, for example, y1.
> y1
      [,1]
 [1,]   33
 [2,]   49
 [3,]   18
 [4,]   61
 [5,]  124
 [6,]   12
 [7,]   89
 [8,]   59
 [9,]   31
[10,]   69
[11,]   20
[12,]   89
[13,]  118
[14,]   67
[15,]   45
[16,]   49
[17,]   80
[18,]   98
[19,]   66
[20,]   52
[21,]   79
[22,]   98
[23,]  188

Each number represent the number of data points in that chromosome, for example, there are 33 datappint in chromosome one. This y1 is dynamically changing, so I use barplot, which generate a chromosome heatmap, the wider the heatmap of each chromosome, the more data/bigger number in that chromosome. Now I want to put the chromosome number from 1 to 23 above the chromosome to show which is which. I use the y1 value to represent the y coordinates, however, the plot just doesn't look right. Can anyone help explain what is wrong with my code?
Here is my code:
ycor <- c(0)
num <- length(y1)
for (i in 2:num){
  a=sum(y1[1:i-1])
  x = y1[i]*0.5
  b = a 
  ycor <- append(ycor, b)
}

par(mar = c(3,3,0,0)) # bottom,left,top,right 
barplot(y1, horiz = F,axes = FALSE, col = colors2, border = NA) # chromosome
text(1,ycor, labels = 23:1, pos = 3)

Here is the plot how it looks:

You see the numbers don't align with the chromosome bars. The width of each bar correlates with the number in y1, which I assume, if I accumulate the numbers, that should give the correct y-coordinates for each chr number. However, the output image doesn't seem to fall into my logic. I don't know which I missed out.
I want the chr number right above each bar representing the chromosome.
By the way, I only want to plot with barplot() and it's compatible functions. ggplot2 is not the same ecosystem.

You need to tag this with whatever language that is.
